# Check for removed users from AD and remove it from GitHub

Tags: github

Our GitHub SAML integration does not remove user from organization when user get removed from AD group. Hence we need to write an automation script to check if the user does not belong to any AD group and remove the user from the GitHub organization to free up the license/seat.

Or at least if there is some kind of script to see users without team.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is.  Is it how to configure your SAML integration to do this properly (in which case, we need to know information about it)?  Is it how to write a script (in what language and with what method to identify removed users)?  Are you also using LDAP, or do we have to use the proprietary AD interfaces?  We'll need a lot more details, so please edit your question to include all of this and anything else you can think of.

Comment: I need some script to check users with 0 team